# how to get and read traces.txt file in android

Tags: android

I want to read and understand what is being written to traces.txt file whenever application forcecloses. I am iplementing app, in that I am fetching data from web and set it to imageview and textview . When I run that app , it takes more time to fetch image and set it to imageview inbetween forceclose is happening and saying activity not responding.

Thanks,
Vishakha.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are running your download in the UI thread.  Any task that will take more than a few hundred miliseconds should not be performed in the UI thread, and should be moved to either an `AsyncTask` or a `Thread` & `Handler`.

- [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
- [Painless threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)
- [Threading](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#threading)
- [Designing for responsiveness](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html)
- [Thread documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html)
- [Handler documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the output of your LogCat instead of the traces.txt to find the reason. Also "activity not responding" sounds like you fetch the image not with an ASyncTask but on the UI-Thread.